# How to start debugging Python 3.6 in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to create some script using this IDE but I can't make it work. I installed Python 3.6, added to path (it's visible finally), installed Python extension (from Microsoft I believe).

Then I tried this manual https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments but I'm stuck on the first step.

When I try the command Select Workspace interpreter I have the following error:

> command 'python.setInterpreter' not found

I'm puzzled what it means. Google can't find anything on this issue, only some github pages that don't exist anymore.

And if I try to start debugging it shows:

> command 'python.python-debug.startSession' not found

OS: Windows 7
Also I want to test scripts created in virtual environment, maybe it's a reason why it doesn't work but I have no idea how to do it.

UPD: I uninstalled and installed the extension again. I don't see these error but debugging still doesn't work just loading CPU and ignoring any breakpoints.

Comment: I believe it's from Microsoft

Comment: Have you tried [setting the interpreter manually](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_manually-specifying-an-interpreter)? Maybe you didn't install to one of the default paths the extension checks?

Comment: Yes it was the first what I did. No effect. Maybe I'm running Visual Code itself wrong but I don't know how I should.

Comment: Don't think you are holding it wrong :-) For what it's worth, I just tried the extension and got bit [by this one](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-python/issues/56). I'd suggest you open up an issue on Github with your problem, might very well be a legitimate bug.

Comment: Didn't find anything on your problem, the error you are getting suggests the extension maybe failed to register the command properly. Could you [file an issue here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-python/issues)? You can enable the developer console `Help -> Developer Console` and see if there are any additional error messages showing up that the GUI doesn't display.

Comment: I don't see anything in debug console. Maybe the VS Code itself should be run from virt. env? But how?

Comment: Okay, there is an update. I uninstalled it and installed again. At least I don't see these errors anymore. But debugging doesn't work anyway. When I start debugging, it loads the CPU much and ignores any breakpoints, showing the output. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

It worked for me going into `~/.vscode/extensions/`, deleting the extension's folder manually and reinstalling it again.

Comment: it helped me, but i do is, instead of deleting the whole ~/.vscode/extensions/ folder i just deleted the folder for the python extension inside the ~/.vscode/extensions/ , which is ~/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2020.6.90262

Answer (score 2):

One way to tackle this problem in Visual Studio Code is to the downgrade the version of Python extension from Microsoft. It can be very easily done through the Visual Studio Code interface. Locate the installed extension using the extension tab, and right click on the extension. Then You will find an option "Install Another Version...". Click on that and you will find a bunch of versions. Select the one that was published, for example, a month ago. Try to see if it works. If it does not, try with the other (preferably older) ones.

Answer (score 0):

In vscode do the following...

1. `ctrl + shift + p`
2. Select `Python: Create Terminal`. this should get rid of "command 
   'python.setInterpreter' not found" problem
3. `ctrl + shift + p`
4. Select `Python: Select Interpreter`
5. Select the path to your virtual environment folder. This will now create a 
   .vscode folder in the root directory of your folder and the settings file 
   with `"python.pythonPath": "venv\\Scripts\\python.exe"` in it
6. You might get "Linter pylint not installed" notification at the bottom
7. Run `pip install -U pylint`
8. Open a document and you should not see the notification anymore