# VS Code not activating extensions [Error: Cannot find module 'vscode']

Tags: visual-studio-code, wsl-2, vscode-remote

Using the WS2 environment, my VS Code stopped activating extensions overnight. When looking at the logs, I come across all extensions installed in the WSL environment: UBUNTU with the error: [error] Activating extension vscode.debug-auto-launch failed due to an error: [error] Error: Cannot find module 'vscode'. More complete examples:

```
2023-08-02 16:43:42.240 [info] ExtensionService#_doActivateExtension vscode.git-base, startup: true, activationEvent: '*', root cause: vscode.git
2023-08-02 16:43:42.248 [error] Activating extension vscode.git-base failed due to an error:
2023-08-02 16:43:42.248 [error] Error: Cannot find module 'vscode'
Require stack:
- /home/luan/.vscode-server/bin/2ccd690cbff1569e4a83d7c43d45101f817401dc/extensions/git-base/dist/extension.js
- /home/luan/.vscode-server/bin/2ccd690cbff1569e4a83d7c43d45101f817401dc/out/vs/loader.js
- /home/luan/.vscode-server/bin/2ccd690cbff1569e4a83d7c43d45101f817401dc/out/bootstrap-amd.js
- /home/luan/.vscode-server/bin/2ccd690cbff1569e4a83d7c43d45101f817401dc/out/bootstrap-fork.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:956:15)
    at Module.Hook.Module.require (/opt/datadog/apm/library/nodejs/node_modules/dd-trace/packages/dd-trace/src/ritm.js:54:29)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.496 (/home/luan/.vscode-server/bin/2ccd690cbff1569e4a83d7c43d45101f817401dc/extensions/git-base/dist/extension.js:1:6523)
    at r (/home/luan/.vscode-server/bin/2ccd690cbff1569e4a83d7c43d45101f817401dc/extensions/git-base/dist/extension.js:1:6640)
    at Object.699 (/home/luan/.vscode-server/bin/2ccd690cbff1569e4a83d7c43d45101f817401dc/extensions/git-base/dist/extension.js:1:117)
    at r (/home/luan/.vscode-server/bin/2ccd690cbff1569e4a83d7c43d45101f817401dc/extensions/git-base/dist/extension.js:1:6640)
    at /home/luan/.vscode-server/bin/2ccd690cbff1569e4a83d7c43d45101f817401dc/extensions/git-base/dist/extension.js:1:6778
    at /home/luan/.vscode-server/bin/2ccd690cbff1569e4a83d7c43d45101f817401dc/extensions/git-base/dist/extension.js:1:6900
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/luan/.vscode-server/bin/2ccd690cbff1569e4a83d7c43d45101f817401dc/extensions/git-base/dist/extension.js:1:7006)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1126:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1180:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1004:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:839:12)
    at Function.u._load (/home/luan/.vscode-server/bin/2ccd690cbff1569e4a83d7c43d45101f817401dc/out/vs/workbench/api/node/extensionHostProcess.js:128:28070)
    at Function.p._load (/home/luan/.vscode-server/bin/2ccd690cbff1569e4a83d7c43d45101f817401dc/out/vs/workbench/api/node/extensionHostProcess.js:128:25404)
    at Function.l._load (/home/luan/.vscode-server/bin/2ccd690cbff1569e4a83d7c43d45101f817401dc/out/vs/workbench/api/node/extensionHostProcess.js:92:22191)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1028:19)
    at Module.Hook.Module.require (/opt/datadog/apm/library/nodejs/node_modules/dd-trace/packages/dd-trace/src/ritm.js:85:33)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Function.i [as __$__nodeRequire] (/home/luan/.vscode-server/bin/2ccd690cbff1569e4a83d7c43d45101f817401dc/out/vs/loader.js:5:98)
    at i.rb (/home/luan/.vscode-server/bin/2ccd690cbff1569e4a83d7c43d45101f817401dc/out/vs/workbench/api/node/extensionHostProcess.js:128:26583)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
```

Does anyone know of any solution?

I have already removed the .vscode-server/ folder from inside WSL2 in an attempt to resolve it, but after the reinstallation, the error persists...

Answer (score 1):

This is caused by [broken Datadog agent that infects any application on the server](https://github.com/DataDog/datadog-agent/issues/21882).

See the related [Visual Studio Code Github issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/201874).